# Should I include teaching feedback from students in my CV?

Tags: teaching, cv

Some time ago, I worked as a teaching assistant in a college. That college had an online form for collecting student feedback. After the end of the year, they sent me an official letter with my final "teaching grade" and the verbal feedback, both of which are very good.

Now, I am near the end of my Ph.D. and I am working on my CV. Should I include this feedback? I thought of including it in the end, after the "recommendations" section, since these are officially-documented recommendations from past students. Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are applying for a job where teaching experience is relevant (e.g., post-doc, assistant professor), you might include it in your CV.

Instead of putting it in the recommendation section, I would put it in the professional experience (or similar section). Something like: "Responsible for teaching instruction XYZ in semester ABC, student feedback: very good".

Comment: And then explain it further on the teaching statement, which is something nearly every academic position asks for.

Comment: If the report you got is a bit elaborate  think you can mention it in achievement or awards srction of cv.other wise put it in your experience section along with feedback received

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure conventions vary, but I know at my university in Australia, when going for promotion, it is important to show a contribution to teaching. However, they specifically suggest avoiding listing individual student comments. The argument is that any academic can find at least a few students who have said something nice about them at some point.

So in summary, I think that official student rated quality of teaching scores are useful, particularly if the scoring is understood by the people reading your CV. My main point would be that selectively taking individual comments is probably not that helpful.

Better means of demonstrating an achievements in teaching include: initiatives in developing content, quality of teaching scores, teaching responsibilities, teaching awards, etc.

Comment: The "student comments" page in my case is formal and includes all comments made by participating students (not only the ones I selected).

Answer (score 1):

It is becoming more and more normal to include a so-called 'pedagogical portfolio' along with your scientific CV. This is due to the fact that many positions actually require a substantial amount of teaching, and one has (chokingly, I know!) found out that experienced teachers are often better teachers.

A ped. portfolio would include:

- Summary of teaching experience
- Experience developing teaching (teaching plans, course plans etc.)
- Experience developing teaching material
- Student feedback